# Copy a footer with image to another word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, footer

I have a macro that copies the footer from one word document to another - this works perfectly however it does not keep the positioning exactly the same - I need a footer to be the same position to the mm. Can anyone help me with any amendments to the code below to make this happen please?

```
Sub UpdateDocuments()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, strDocNm As String
    Dim wdDocSrc As Document, wdDocTgt As Document, HdFt As HeaderFooter
    Dim aStory As Range
    Dim aField As Field
    Dim oldFilename As String
    Dim bmRange As Range
    Dim Response As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim l As Integer
```

THEN THE ACTUAL CODE TO REPLACE THE FOOTER IS (this also adds the name of the document into the footer)

```
or Each HdFt In .Sections.First.Footers
    If HdFt.Exists Then
      If wdDocSrc.Sections.First.Footers(HdFt.Index).Exists Then
        HdFt.Range.FormattedText = wdDocSrc.Sections.First.Footers(HdFt.Index).Range.FormattedText

                'FILE NAME CODE
                'Check if the DocName bookmark exists
                If wdDocTgt.Bookmarks.Exists("DocName") = True Then
                'If DocName bookmark does exist do this
                Set bmRange = wdDocTgt.Bookmarks("DocName").Range
                        'NEW gets the name of the target document and removed the .doc extension
                        oldFilename = wdDocTgt.Name
                        If Right(oldFilename, 5) = ".docx" Then
                        oldFilename = Left(oldFilename, Len(oldFilename) - 5)
                            ElseIf Right(oldFilename, 4) = ".doc" Then
                            oldFilename = Left(oldFilename, Len(oldFilename) - 4)

                'Update bmRange (DocName bookmark) with the file name with no extension
                bmRange.Text = oldFilename
                        End If
                End If

                 If wdDocTgt.Bookmarks.Exists("DocName2") = True Then
                'If DocName bookmark does exist do this

                 Set bmRange = wdDocTgt.Bookmarks("DocName2").Range
                 'set bmRange as blank so as to no duplicate the name
                 bmRange.Text = " "
                    'NEW gets the name of the target document and removed the .doc extension
                        oldFilename = ""
                        oldFilename = wdDocTgt.Name
                        If Right(oldFilename, 5) = ".docx" Then
                        oldFilename = Left(oldFilename, Len(oldFilename) - 5)
                            ElseIf Right(oldFilename, 4) = ".doc" Then
                            oldFilename = Left(oldFilename, Len(oldFilename) - 4)

                'Update bmRange (DocName bookmark) with the file name with no extension
                 bmRange.Text = oldFilename
                 End If
             End If
            'END FILE NAME CODE

      End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solved the problem:

```
wdDocTgt.PageSetup.FooterDistance = wdDocSrc.PageSetup.FooterDistance
```